# How to convey schema information when using pipe to process RDD with external program?

Tags: apache-spark

I've successfully used `RDD.pipe` to pipe an RDD out to a python program one line at a time.

The problem is that the python program will not know how to interpret that line unless it has some information about the schema.

Is there any way to pass the RDD schema information to the external program?

I was hoping that maybe the version of `RDD.pipe` that allows passing `printPipeContext` and `printRDDElement` might be of use, but I cannot tell from the ScalaDoc or the source what their purpose is.

Can they be used to convey schema information to the external program? If so how? If not, what are they useful for? A simple example would be helpful.

Here is my current (passing) test case:

```scala
test("Pipe to python (with metadata)") {

    val dataRdd: RDD[Row] = SPARK_SESSION.sparkContext.makeRDD(
        Seq(
            Row("first", 2.0, 7.0, "A"),
            Row("second", 3.5, 2.5, "B"),
            Row("third", 7.0, 5.9, "B"),
            Row("fourth", 27.0, 15.8, "A")
        )
    )

    val scriptPath = HOME + "/src/test/resources/python/process.py"

    def printPipeContext(prnt: String => Unit): Unit = {
        // what could go here to convey schema?
    }

    def printRDDElement(record:Row, f: String => Unit): Unit = {
        // what could go here to convey schema?
    }

    val resultRdd = dataRdd.pipe(Seq(scriptPath), Map("SEPARATOR" -> ","), 
                                 printPipeContext = null, printRDDElement = null) 

    val result: Array[String] = resultRdd.collect()
    assertResult(
      strip("""hello first ,  14.0
              |hello second ,  8.75
              |hello third ,  41.3
              |hello fourth ,  426.6""")) {
      result.mkString("\n")
    }
}
```

Here is the external python program.

It currently assumes that columns 2 and 3 are Floats and multiplies them together.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

for line in sys.stdin:
    values = line[1:-2].split(os.environ['SEPARATOR'])
    print "hello " + values[0], ", ", (float(values[1]) * float(values[2]))
```

But what if what I want to do was multiply all Float columns together? How can I tell which columns have type Float?

Comment: The entire row is passed as string to STDIN of the process that you pipe with. You can probably pass a Map explaining which column is of which type and then parse the map in your script and type cast accordingly.  Commenting because I'd like to know more about the usage of `printPipeContext` and `printRDDElement` in case you find a solution with them. :)

Comment: I was hoping that the schema information could be sent just once, and not need to be reparsed in python for every row. It looks like printPipeContext is called for every row.